# DiagrammeR - could not find function "grViz"

Tags: r, diagrammer

i am new to R and just did my first install with Version 3.5 via cran sources on a Kubuntu 18.04 PC alongside with Rstudio server.

Now i am playing around a little by trying and looking at some examples.
For a flow diagram i installed the DiagrammR package in RStudio.

But when i copy+paste examples from http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html

like

```
grViz("
digraph boxes_and_circles {

  # a 'graph' statement
  graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]

  # several 'node' statements
  node [shape = box,
        fontname = Helvetica]
  A; B; C; D; E; F

  node [shape = circle,
        fixedsize = true,
        width = 0.9] // sets as circles
  1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8

  # several 'edge' statements
  A->1 B->2 B->3 B->4 C->A
  1->D E->A 2->4 1->5 1->F
  E->6 4->6 5->7 6->7 3->8
}
")
```

it leads to

> Error in grViz("\ndigraph boxes_and_circles {\n\n  # a 'graph'
>   statement\n  graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]\n\n  # several
>   'node' statements\n  node [shape = box,\n        fontname =
>   Helvetica]\n  A; B; C; D; E; F\n\n  node [shape = circle,\n
>   fixedsize = true,\n        width = 0.9] // sets as circles\n  1; 2; 3;
>   4; 5; 6; 7; 8\n\n  # several 'edge' statements\n  A->1 B->2 B->3 B->4
>   C->A\n  1->D E->A 2->4 1->5 1->F\n  E->6 4->6 5->7 6->7 3->8\n}\n") : 
>   could not find function "grViz"

The same goes for every other example i try.

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you load the library by `library(DiagrammeR)` before executing the function?

Answer (score 0):

Like Jay.sf stated, you should run, in the console of RStudio, this line:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
```

And once the library es loaded, your graph will work again.